# FormatMessage returning error code 8 (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to print the last message from WinApi to the console. Sounds simple, or so I thought. I made this simple enough function, but I'm getting an error code 8 (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). I'm not sure how this could be. I didn't find anything online either. Here's what I've got:

```
static inline void printLastMessage()
{
    LPTSTR lpMsgBuf; 
    if(FormatMessage((FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS), NULL,
                 GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    wprintf(L"Error: %s\n", lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
```

The resulting buffer looks like this in the console:

```
Error: (null)
```

I've also tried FormatMessageW, but it didn't make a difference. (And it seems like FormatMessage is defined as FormatMessageW with UNICODE)

I'm using MinGW's GCC with C11, Windows SDK 10.0.22621.

Edit: Updated (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf. Current code:

```
static inline void printLastMessage()
{
    LPTSTR lpMsgBuf; 
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error code: %d\n", err);
    if(FormatMessage((FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS), NULL,
                 err, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error Code (FormatMessage): %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    wprintf(L"Error: %s\n", lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
```

And output:

```
Error code: 87
Error:
```

Comment: You need to pass the address of the pointer for the buffer to allocate, so `(LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf` instead of `lpMsgBuf`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ahh yes you must be right. I'm new to those windows types, wasn't quite sure how it was to be handled. I still don't get my error, but at least the FormatMessage seems to work now.

Comment: @EtiennePoulin since you are using the `TCHAR` version of `FormatMessage()`, use `_tprintf()` to match.  Also, if  `FormatMessage()` fails, `lpMsgBuf` is invalid so DON'T print OR free it.

Comment: Please don't update your question and turn it into a different question. If the title says you're getting `ERROR_NO_ENOUGH_MEMORY`, then asking about error code 87 isn't meaningful.

Comment: @IInspectable The error code is unrelated, this is to show that GetLastError() returns an actual error code, but this code isn't getting translated. But you're right, this isn't the original question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I was missing a return, thank you. As for _tprintf(), I'm not sure what it's part of but I can't seem to find it. I found however that it's supposedly defined as wprintf (what I'm using) when UNICODE is defined, which it is.

Comment: `_tprintf` expands to `wprintf` if `_UNICODE` is defined (not `UNICODE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was a compiler issue. Changing from MinGW from https://www.mingw-w64.org/ to the version over at https://winlibs.com/ makes the exact same code run just fine...

Comment: Did you also build without pointing to Windows SDK?

Comment: @BrechtSanders For the headers, yes. However, I still have to use it for the .lib files that don't seem to be included with MinGW (such as gdi32.lib). I just copy them over however, this doesn't seem to cause any issues.

Comment: That's still a bad idea. In MinGW `gdi32.lib` would be called `libgdi32.a` instead, and a simple `-lgdi32` linker flag will know where to find it.

Comment: @BrechtSanders You're right, these do actually work. I had kind of dismissed them as being for linux (.a .o .so kind of thing) but now I suppose they wouldn't have included linux libraries on a windows only implementation. I'm using those from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using MinGW's GCC with C11, Windows SDK 10.0.22621.

That doesn't make sense. MinGW comes with it's own Win32 API libraries. You shouldn't mix that with Windows SDK. This may result in undefined behaviour.

Build your code purely with MinGW and stay away from Windows SDK, or use MSVC with Windows SDK.

I tried your code with MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ and see no issue. Here's how I made your code into a standalone program `test.cc`:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void printLastMessage()
{
    LPTSTR lpMsgBuf; 
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error code: %d\n", err);
    if(FormatMessage((FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS), NULL,
                 err, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error Code (FormatMessage): %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    wprintf(L"Error: %s\n", lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

int main ()
{
    printLastMessage();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I built the code like this:

```bash
g++ test.cc
```

After running the resulting `a.exe` I get:

```
Error code: 126
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

So it looks like your code is working, you just need to build it in pure MinGW/MinGW-w64.

Comment: Did you mean to post a comment? Nothing here seems to acknowledge the specific error, or provide a solution.

Comment: The error is caused by mixing MinGW and Windows SDK. The solution is to build correctly without pointing to Windows SDK.

Comment: Please provide profound proof for that hypothesis.

Comment: Just added the output of the exact same code being built like this.

Comment: Your understanding of *"exact same code"* is somehow very different from my understanding of *"exact same code"*.

Comment: Okay I added headers and `main` so it would actually be runnable.

Comment: And you added code that calls `GetLastError`, and you change code from passing a pointer to passing the address of a pointer. Yup, that's *"exactly the same code"*...

Comment: No, I took the edited code from the requester.

Comment: There's no improvement whatsoever. It's still lacking every last bit of evidence. Under profound proof I would understand a binary built with mismatching libraries, that exhibits the described behavior (of the original code, obviously), ideally with disassembly that illustrates where things break (and why). So far all we see is *some* code compiled in *some* environment that doesn't exhibit the issue described by the question.

Comment: I don't have MSVC on my system. I justed wanted to share my experience.

Comment: Sure. That's a comment then. Though I don't see why you would need MSVC installed on your system to repro the issue. Did you fail to understand the issue?

Comment: I meant Windows SDK, sorry. I'm not going to taint my system with it, so I will leave it with that. Thanks anyway for helping me improve my answer.

Comment: @BrechtSanders Hey, thanks for your answer. That it runs on your system shows that my config/compiling might be the issue. I didn't use windows sdk at first, but it seemed like MinGW was missing a few headers. For example, stringapiset.h isn't included, so I grabbed it from the windows sdk. However, removing windows sdk doesn't fix my issue I'm afraid. Also, I'm compiling with gcc and not g++.

Comment: @EtiennePoulin Which version of GCC are you using exactly?

Comment: More recent MinGW-w64 versions include more headers. Your code builds fine with a recent version from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: @BrechtSanders I'm using 6.3.0, which seems to be the latest MinGW offers. For now, that's fine I dropped that header and made the function I needed myself, so I'm not relying on the sdk anymore. Is there a reason to use winlibs over the official download from the MinGW website?

Comment: @BrechtSanders Using the winlibs compiler makes it work flawlessly... Not sure why, but hey guess that's the one I'm using from now on.